# Rhythmic Analysis in a neo-Riemannian Manner

Tags: rhythm, analysis

I was looking at the differences between neo-Riemannian (interrelational) and Schenkerian (hyper-tonal) analysis, which are nearly diametrically opposed, and it occurred to me that every rhythmic analysis I've ever encountered is both (a) not that fully fleshed out, and (b) very metric-centered.

This makes some sense, but I wonder if someone has considered such a neo-Riemannian approach to rhythm.  Does there exist anywhere a type of rhythmic analysis that is all about the interrelations from one figure to the next, a-la neo-Riemannian style analysis?

Comment: Perhaps someone with more rep than me could add the tag Neo-Riemannian?  It doesn't currently exist, but surely on a SE that purports to talk about music theory, it should.  I mean, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question!

Neo-Riemannian theory is a very broad subfield of music theory, but we can generalize and say that it is an *associative* theory. In other words, it is a network-based theory that relates how a given entity relates to other entities. (You addressed this, you just called it "interrelational.")

Schenkerian theory, on the other hand, is a *hierarchical* theory. It is a theory of monotonality, which means that there is a single tonic that governs a given span of music. Thus it is a theory that relates how all given entities relate to a *single governing entity*. (You called this "hyper-tonal.")

Now we can look at the distinction between rhythm and meter. Whereas rhythm is a pattern of articulations, meter is the hierarchy of that pattern. Thus a study of meter is necessarily hierarchical, and so an associative system like neo-Riemannian theory would not be ideal to study rhythm. But again, you implicitly address this, because you specifically asked for approaches to *rhythm*, not to *meter*. (You did your homework!)

But the problem is that music theorists often join rhythm and meter in their analysis, so it's tough to find analyses of *only* rhythm (the associative connections), with no concern for the meter (the hierarchy of it all).

Nevertheless, you may want to check out:

- Brad Osborn's look at [maximally even rhythm in Radiohead](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj20Mu_4fbTAhUF6yYKHaQlC54QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkuscholarworks.ku.edu%2Fhandle%2F1808%2F19135&usg=AFQjCNFOhjH-gSytVYH9K5YCKHSI08peMQ&sig2=1p19BZGoDueWTL0Wz0IgQQ).
- Guy Capuzzo on [rhythm in Meshuggah](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&ved=0ahUKEwjd0Ozx4fbTAhWI5iYKHdkqAIE4ChAWCEIwBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsocietymusictheory.org%2Ffiles%2F2014_handouts%2Fcapuzzo.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFHiPi9wmxcpPFEVG6nsWWc1xLadA&sig2=c4SwLPscZmmrvrme3lJYTQ).
- Rick Cohn on [beat-class sets in Reich](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3090631).
- Or Cohn's recent look at [funky rhythms](http://mtosmt.org/issues/mto.16.22.2/mto.16.22.2.cohn.html) (which is probably farthest from what you're looking for).

Comment: It will take me some time to absorb this material, but I have upvoted, because this is an insightful answer.  Thanks!

Comment: If the music of Haydn, Mozart, etc. is metrical, does it mean the *composers* had a hierarchical approach to rhythm?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I'm not sure what you're asking. I think it's safe to say they had a hierarchical approach to *meter* (since meter is, by definition, hierarchical), but I don't know what hierarchical *rhythm* would be.

Comment: @Richard, I was wondering if there is single governing concept for rhythm similar to what you explained about Schenker and tonality? Maybe another way to ask is: the OP is looking for a figure to figure Analysis. Would the opposite be a figure to meter analysis? Are there any books for that topic? I'd post a new question, but I don't really have a clear question.

Comment: @Richard, I think I need to start with reading Cooper and Meyer, the Rhythmic Structure of Music.